# How to link RT2870STA.dat to an AP for wifi connectivity with TP-Link T2UH AC600?

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, networkmanager

I bought a TP-Link Archer T2UH AC600 wireless adapter, I have been able to compile the drivers fine but the issue I'm facing right now is the `RT2870STA.dat` file. I'm trying to guide from the manual TP-Link provides for linux machines, but I'm confused of what to do with the empty fields and most fields I do not understand what they mean.

```
Default
CountryRegion=5
CountryRegionABand=7
CountryCode=CA
SSID=Rogers343 <--#nomyreal SSID
NetworkType=Infra
WirelessMode=9
Channel=0
BeaconPeriod=100
TxPower=100
BGProtection=0
TxPreamble=0
RTSThreshold=2347
FragThreshold=2346
TxBurst=1
WmmCapable=0
AckPolicy=0;0;0;0
AuthMode=WPA2PSK
EncrypType=NONE
WPAPSK=1234567
DefaultKeyID=1
Key1Type=0
Key1Str=
Key2Type=0
Key2Str=
Key3Type=0
Key3Str=
Key4Type=0
Key4Str=
PSMode=CAM
FastRoaming=0
RoamThreshold=70
HT_RDG=1
HT_EXTCHA=0
HT_OpMode=1
HT_MpduDensity=4
HT_BW=1
HT_AutoBA=1
HT_BADecline=0
HT_AMSDU=0
HT_BAWinSize=64
HT_GI=1
HT_MCS=33
HT_MIMOPSMode=3
EthConvertMode=
EthCloneMac=
IEEE80211H=0
TGnWifiTest=0
WirelessEvent=0
MeshId=MESH
MeshAutoLink=1
MeshAuthMode=OPEN
MeshEncrypType=NONE
MeshWPAKEY=
MeshDefaultkey=1
MeshWEPKEY=
CarrierDetect=0
```

There are some empty field and I don't know what kind of values goes in there. I understand to change the `SSID` to the name of my wifi connection. I'm not so sure what value goes in `CountryCode` I'm in Canada, in `AuthMode` I think I should be putting `WPA`&`WPA2Personal` since that is what my wifi connection is currently using. In `EncrypType` the file automatically has none I'm not sure what that is for, and `WPAPSK` would be my password. There also a lot other empty fields which I don't know what to do with them. 
Because I'm trying to set up my wireless adapter in Kali Linux using iwpriv and the configuration requires me to move `RT2870STA.dat` to `/etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat` in order to proceed. Also in order for me to request an ip with dhclient I need to have the Access Point's SSID configured. My question is how do I get the AP's SSID? If I compared the value of my wlan0 interface to my ra0 interface the wlan0 Access Point looks like a MAC address and I don't see a MAC address on the adapter and I don't know what value to put in there. Here are the steps I took to set up the adapter with `iwpriv`

```
iwpriv ra0 set NetworkType=Infra
iwpriv ra0 set AuthMode=WPA2PSK
iwpriv ra0 set EncrypType=TKIP
iwpriv ra0 set SSID="Rogers343"
iwpriv ra0 set WPAPSK=1234567 <-- not my acutal pswd 
iwpriv ra0 set WirelessMode=14
```

After I enter those commands here's what `iwconfig ra0` shows

```
Ralink STA  ESSID:"Rogers343"  Nickname:"MT7610U_STA"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=5.18 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Link Quality=10/100  Signal level:0 dBm  Noise level:0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

output of  `dmesg`when the adapter is plugged in.

```
  3539.786506] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
    [ 3539.910506] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=761a
    [ 3539.910508] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [ 3539.910509] usb 1-1.3: Product: WiFi
    [ 3539.910510] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: MediaTek
    [ 3539.910511] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 1.0
    [ 3539.911075] 

                   === pAd = ffffc64740b25000, size = 892576 ===

    [ 3539.911171] <-- RTMPAllocTxRxRingMemory, Status=0
    [ 3539.911300] <-- RTMPAllocAdapterBlock, Status=0
    [ 3539.911493] ==>RT65xx_WLAN_ChipOnOff(): OnOff:1, Reset= 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl:0x0, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xff000002
    [ 3539.912593] MCUType = 2
    [ 3539.912869] NVM is EFUSE
    [ 3539.912870] Endpoint(8) is for In-band Command
    [ 3539.912871] Endpoint(4) is for WMM0 AC0
    [ 3539.912871] Endpoint(5) is for WMM0 AC1
    [ 3539.912872] Endpoint(6) is for WMM0 AC2
    [ 3539.912872] Endpoint(7) is for WMM0 AC3
    [ 3539.912873] Endpoint(9) is for WMM1 AC0
    [ 3539.912874] Endpoint(84) is for Data-In
    [ 3539.912874] Endpoint(85) is for Command Rsp
    [ 3632.642059] -->RTUSBVenderReset
    [ 3632.642162] <--RTUSBVenderReset
    [ 3632.647128] fw version:0.1.00 build:7640
    [ 3632.647130] build time:201308221655____
    [ 3632.647135] ilm length = 68780(bytes)
    [ 3632.647136] dlm length = 11476(bytes)
    [ 3632.729684] #
    [ 3632.736655] loading fw......
    [ 3632.857890] #
    [ 3633.074167] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740ba61e0!
    [ 3633.074169] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740ba6250!
    [ 3633.074177] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740b38c38!
    [ 3633.074178] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740b38e18!
    [ 3633.086233] cfg_mode=5
    [ 3633.086236] wmode_band_equal(): Band Not Equal!
    [ 3633.086350] Key1Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 3633.086361] Key2Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 3633.086372] Key3Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 3633.086383] Key4Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 3633.086687] 1. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 3633.086688] 2. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 3633.086690] NVM is Efuse and its size =1d[1e0-1fc] 
    [ 3633.097715] /root/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../chips/mt76x0.c:2114 assert (pAd->TxPower[choffset].Channel == 36)failed
    [ 3633.111176] ERROR!!! E2PROM: WRONG VERSION 0x2, should be 1
    [ 3633.115302] mt76x0_read_tx_alc_info_from_eeprom: EEPROM_MT76x0_TEMPERATURE_OFFSET (0xD1) = 0xf8
    [ 3633.115303] mt76x0_read_tx_alc_info_from_eeprom: TemperatureOffset = 0xfffffff8
    [ 3633.115303] Temperature Tx ALC not enabled
    [ 3633.130303] 3. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 3633.130305] AntCfgInit: primary/secondary ant 0/1
    [ 3633.138969] RTMPSetPhyMode: channel is out of range, use first channel=1 
    [ 3633.140555] MCS Set = ff 00 00 00 01
    [ 3633.150491] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
    [ 3633.151431] 0x1300 = 00064300
    [ 3633.151432] RTMPDrvSTAOpen(1):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 3633.151556] RTMPDrvSTAOpen(2):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 4260.799872] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.799965] Bulk In Failed. Status=-71, BIIdx=0x0, BIRIdx=0x0, actual_length= 0x0
    [ 4260.804373] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.832271] #
    [ 4260.834242] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.838494] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.841272] #
    [ 4260.842743] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.846994] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.850247] #
    [ 4260.851243] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.855520] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.859274] #
    [ 4260.996257] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.998887] #
    [ 4261.000507] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4261.003855] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-71),TxFlags=0x0, ReqType=IN, Req=0x7, Idx=0x1000,pAd->Flags=0x31080002
    [ 4261.004758] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4261.007759] Bulk In Failed. Status=-71, BIIdx=0x0, BIRIdx=0x0, actual_length= 0x0
    [ 4261.009009] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4261.030639] #
    [ 4261.034139] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 8
    [ 4261.034509] receive cmd msg fail(-108)
    [ 4261.034511] usb_rx_cmd_msg_complete:submit urb fail(-19)
    [ 4261.034517] usb_rx_cmd_msg_submit:submit urb fail(-19)
    [ 4261.034519] rtusb_disconnect: unregister usbnet usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3
    [ 4261.034522] RtmpOSNetDevDetach(): RtmpOSNetDeviceDetach(), dev->name=ra0!
    [ 4261.035606] #
    [ 4261.035608] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-19),TxFlags=0x0, ReqType=IN, Req=0x7, Idx=0x1000,pAd->Flags=0x31080542
    [ 4261.035609] CMDTHREAD_RESET_BULK_IN: Cannot do bulk in because flags(0x31080542) on !
    [ 4261.049617] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.049668] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.049668] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.049669] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.049673] tx_kickout_fail_count = 0
    [ 4261.049673] tx_timeout_fail_count = 0
    [ 4261.049674] rx_receive_fail_count = 58
    [ 4261.049674] alloc_cmd_msg = 7672
    [ 4261.049675] free_cmd_msg = 7672
    [ 4261.132674] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.132677] ==>RT65xx_WLAN_ChipOnOff(): OnOff:0, Reset= 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl:0xff000003, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xffffffff
    [ 4261.132677] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.132678] VendrCmdMultiWrite_nBytes failed!
    [ 4261.132698] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.132708] ---> RTMPFreeTxRxRingMemory
    [ 4261.132722] <--- RTMPFreeTxRxRingMemory
    [ 4261.132759]  RTUSB disconnect successfully
    [ 4981.190839] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
    [ 4981.315282] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=761a
    [ 4981.315284] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [ 4981.315285] usb 1-1.3: Product: WiFi
    [ 4981.315286] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: MediaTek
    [ 4981.315287] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 1.0
    [ 4981.315819] 

                   === pAd = ffffc64740b25000, size = 892576 ===

    [ 4981.315904] <-- RTMPAllocTxRxRingMemory, Status=0
    [ 4981.316006] <-- RTMPAllocAdapterBlock, Status=0
    [ 4981.316133] ==>RT65xx_WLAN_ChipOnOff(): OnOff:1, Reset= 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl:0x0, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xff000002
    [ 4981.317259] MCUType = 2
    [ 4981.317507] NVM is EFUSE
    [ 4981.317508] Endpoint(8) is for In-band Command
    [ 4981.317509] Endpoint(4) is for WMM0 AC0
    [ 4981.317509] Endpoint(5) is for WMM0 AC1
    [ 4981.317510] Endpoint(6) is for WMM0 AC2
    [ 4981.317511] Endpoint(7) is for WMM0 AC3
    [ 4981.317511] Endpoint(9) is for WMM1 AC0
    [ 4981.317512] Endpoint(84) is for Data-In
    [ 4981.317512] Endpoint(85) is for Command Rsp
```

Then I do `systemctl restart network-manager.service`
and at this point I get kicked off my network but I can see that both wifi icons are appearing in the network manager but both cards say "Unavailable" as you can see in the image below and no networks are being picked up.
[image: Image of the Network-Manager]
Here is the output of `dmesg`after this occurs

```
238.916761] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load brcm/BCM.hcd (-2)
    [  238.916766] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
    [  238.916769] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
    [  239.115808] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
    [  239.310935] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: link down
    [  239.310991] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
    [  239.311865] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
    [  240.719041] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0x8d on isa0060/serio0).
    [  240.719043] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e00d <keycode>' to make it known.
    [  285.069677] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
    [  954.235212] perf: interrupt took too long (2506 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
    [ 1193.231540] perf: interrupt took too long (3135 > 3132), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63750
    [ 1470.857282] perf: interrupt took too long (4013 > 3918), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 49750
    [ 2345.359889] perf: interrupt took too long (5032 > 5016), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 39500
    [ 3539.786506] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
    [ 3539.910506] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=761a
    [ 3539.910508] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [ 3539.910509] usb 1-1.3: Product: WiFi
    [ 3539.910510] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: MediaTek
    [ 3539.910511] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 1.0
    [ 3539.911075] 

                  === pAd = ffffc64740b25000, size = 892576 ===

    [ 3539.911171] <-- RTMPAllocTxRxRingMemory, Status=0
    [ 3539.911300] <-- RTMPAllocAdapterBlock, Status=0
    [ 3539.911493] ==>RT65xx_WLAN_ChipOnOff(): OnOff:1, Reset= 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl:0x0, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xff000002
    [ 3539.912593] MCUType = 2
    [ 3539.912869] NVM is EFUSE
    [ 3539.912870] Endpoint(8) is for In-band Command
    [ 3539.912871] Endpoint(4) is for WMM0 AC0
    [ 3539.912871] Endpoint(5) is for WMM0 AC1
    [ 3539.912872] Endpoint(6) is for WMM0 AC2
    [ 3539.912872] Endpoint(7) is for WMM0 AC3
    [ 3539.912873] Endpoint(9) is for WMM1 AC0
    [ 3539.912874] Endpoint(84) is for Data-In
    [ 3539.912874] Endpoint(85) is for Command Rsp
    [ 3632.642059] -->RTUSBVenderReset
    [ 3632.642162] <--RTUSBVenderReset
    [ 3632.647128] fw version:0.1.00 build:7640
    [ 3632.647130] build time:201308221655____
    [ 3632.647135] ilm length = 68780(bytes)
    [ 3632.647136] dlm length = 11476(bytes)
    [ 3632.729684] #
    [ 3632.736655] loading fw......
    [ 3632.857890] #
    [ 3633.074167] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740ba61e0!
    [ 3633.074169] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740ba6250!
    [ 3633.074170] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740ba62c0!
    [ 3633.074171] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740ba6170!
    [ 3633.086233] cfg_mode=5
    [ 3633.086236] wmode_band_equal(): Band Not Equal!
    [ 3633.086350] Key1Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 3633.086361] Key2Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 3633.086372] Key3Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 3633.086383] Key4Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 3633.086687] 1. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 3633.086688] 2. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 3633.086690] NVM is Efuse and its size =1d[1e0-1fc] 
    [ 3633.097715] /root/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../chips/mt76x0.c:2114 assert (pAd->TxPower[choffset].Channel == 36)failed
    [ 3633.111176] ERROR!!! E2PROM: WRONG VERSION 0x2, should be 1
    [ 3633.115302] mt76x0_read_tx_alc_info_from_eeprom: EEPROM_MT76x0_TEMPERATURE_OFFSET (0xD1) = 0xf8
    [ 3633.115303] mt76x0_read_tx_alc_info_from_eeprom: TemperatureOffset = 0xfffffff8
    [ 3633.115303] Temperature Tx ALC not enabled
    [ 3633.130303] 3. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 3633.130305] AntCfgInit: primary/secondary ant 0/1
    [ 3633.138969] RTMPSetPhyMode: channel is out of range, use first channel=1 
    [ 3633.140555] MCS Set = ff 00 00 00 01
    [ 3633.150491] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
    [ 3633.151431] 0x1300 = 00064300
    [ 3633.151432] RTMPDrvSTAOpen(1):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 3633.151556] RTMPDrvSTAOpen(2):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 4260.799872] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.799965] Bulk In Failed. Status=-71, BIIdx=0x0, BIRIdx=0x0, actual_length= 0x0
    [ 4260.804373] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.808616] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.812867] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.817116] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.898248] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.900248] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-71),TxFlags=0x0, ReqType=IN, Req=0x7, Idx=0x1000,pAd->Flags=0x31080002
    [ 4260.902500] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4260.904250] Bulk In Failed. Status=-71, BIIdx=0x0, BIRIdx=0x0, actual_length= 0x0
    [ 4260.945005] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4261.000507] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4261.003855] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-71),TxFlags=0x0, ReqType=IN, Req=0x7, Idx=0x1000,pAd->Flags=0x31080002
    [ 4261.004758] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4261.007759] Bulk In Failed. Status=-71, BIIdx=0x0, BIRIdx=0x0, actual_length= 0x0
    [ 4261.009009] receive cmd msg fail(-71)
    [ 4261.034139] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 8
    [ 4261.034509] receive cmd msg fail(-108)
    [ 4261.034511] usb_rx_cmd_msg_complete:submit urb fail(-19)
    [ 4261.034517] usb_rx_cmd_msg_submit:submit urb fail(-19)
    [ 4261.034519] rtusb_disconnect: unregister usbnet usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3
    [ 4261.034522] RtmpOSNetDevDetach(): RtmpOSNetDeviceDetach(), dev->name=ra0!
    [ 4261.035606] #
    [ 4261.035608] RTUSB_VendorRequest failed(-19),TxFlags=0x0, ReqType=IN, Req=0x7, Idx=0x1000,pAd->Flags=0x31080542
    [ 4261.035609] CMDTHREAD_RESET_BULK_IN: Cannot do bulk in because flags(0x31080542) on !
    [ 4261.049617] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.049668] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.049668] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.049669] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.049673] tx_kickout_fail_count = 0
    [ 4261.049673] tx_timeout_fail_count = 0
    [ 4261.049674] rx_receive_fail_count = 58
    [ 4261.049674] alloc_cmd_msg = 7672
    [ 4261.049675] free_cmd_msg = 7672
    [ 4261.132674] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.132677] ==>RT65xx_WLAN_ChipOnOff(): OnOff:0, Reset= 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl:0xff000003, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xffffffff
    [ 4261.132677] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.132678] VendrCmdMultiWrite_nBytes failed!
    [ 4261.132698] WIFI device has been disconnected
    [ 4261.132708] ---> RTMPFreeTxRxRingMemory
    [ 4261.132722] <--- RTMPFreeTxRxRingMemory
    [ 4261.132759]  RTUSB disconnect successfully
    [ 4981.190839] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
    [ 4981.315282] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=761a
    [ 4981.315284] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [ 4981.315285] usb 1-1.3: Product: WiFi
    [ 4981.315286] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: MediaTek
    [ 4981.315287] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 1.0
    [ 4981.315819] 

                  === pAd = ffffc64740b25000, size = 892576 ===

    [ 4981.315904] <-- RTMPAllocTxRxRingMemory, Status=0
    [ 4981.316006] <-- RTMPAllocAdapterBlock, Status=0
    [ 4981.316133] ==>RT65xx_WLAN_ChipOnOff(): OnOff:1, Reset= 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl:0x0, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xff000002
    [ 4981.317259] MCUType = 2
    [ 4981.317507] NVM is EFUSE
    [ 4981.317508] Endpoint(8) is for In-band Command
    [ 4981.317509] Endpoint(4) is for WMM0 AC0
    [ 4981.317509] Endpoint(5) is for WMM0 AC1
    [ 4981.317510] Endpoint(6) is for WMM0 AC2
    [ 4981.317511] Endpoint(7) is for WMM0 AC3
    [ 4981.317511] Endpoint(9) is for WMM1 AC0
    [ 4981.317512] Endpoint(84) is for Data-In
    [ 4981.317512] Endpoint(85) is for Command Rsp
    [ 5382.065830] -->RTUSBVenderReset
    [ 5382.066025] <--RTUSBVenderReset
    [ 5382.070992] fw version:0.1.00 build:7640
    [ 5382.070994] build time:201308221655____
    [ 5382.071000] ilm length = 68780(bytes)
    [ 5382.071000] dlm length = 11476(bytes)
    [ 5382.152631] #
    [ 5382.158632] loading fw......
    [ 5382.276688] #
    [ 5382.494398] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740ba61e0!
    [ 5382.494400] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740ba6250!
    [ 5382.494401] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740ba62c0!
    [ 5382.494402] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740ba6170!
    [ 5382.494408] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740b38c38!
    [ 5382.494409] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740b38e18!
    [ 5382.494466] cfg_mode=5
    [ 5382.494468] wmode_band_equal(): Band Not Equal!
    [ 5382.494582] Key1Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 5382.494593] Key2Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 5382.494604] Key3Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 5382.494616] Key4Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 5382.494856] 1. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 5382.494856] 2. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 5382.494858] NVM is Efuse and its size =1d[1e0-1fc] 
    [ 5382.506903] /root/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../chips/mt76x0.c:2114 assert (pAd->TxPower[choffset].Channel == 36)failed
    [ 5382.517405] ERROR!!! E2PROM: WRONG VERSION 0x2, should be 1
    [ 5382.521530] mt76x0_read_tx_alc_info_from_eeprom: EEPROM_MT76x0_TEMPERATURE_OFFSET (0xD1) = 0xf8
    [ 5382.521531] mt76x0_read_tx_alc_info_from_eeprom: TemperatureOffset = 0xfffffff8
    [ 5382.521532] Temperature Tx ALC not enabled
    [ 5382.537531] 3. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 5382.537533] AntCfgInit: primary/secondary ant 0/1
    [ 5382.542790] RTMPSetPhyMode: channel is out of range, use first channel=1 
    [ 5382.544283] MCS Set = ff 00 00 00 01
    [ 5382.554214] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
    [ 5382.555157] 0x1300 = 00064300
    [ 5382.555158] RTMPDrvSTAOpen(1):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 5382.555314] RTMPDrvSTAOpen(2):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 5482.218330] ===>rt_ioctl_giwscan. 2(2) BSS returned, data->length = 317
    [ 5550.260554] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
    [ 5550.293209] ERROR!!! RTMPSetTimer failed, Halt in Progress!
    [ 5550.300208] ==>RT65xx_WLAN_ChipOnOff(): OnOff:0, Reset= 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl:0xff000003, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xff000003
    [ 5550.303830] receive cmd msg fail(-2)
    [ 5550.303842] tx_kickout_fail_count = 0
    [ 5550.303844] tx_timeout_fail_count = 0
    [ 5550.303845] rx_receive_fail_count = 0
    [ 5550.303846] alloc_cmd_msg = 6981
    [ 5550.303846] free_cmd_msg = 6981
    [ 5550.359595] ==>RT65xx_WLAN_ChipOnOff(): OnOff:1, Reset= 0, pAd->WlanFunCtrl:0xff000000, Reg-WlanFunCtrl=0xff000000
    [ 5550.366721] -->RTUSBVenderReset
    [ 5550.366846] <--RTUSBVenderReset
    [ 5550.371809] fw version:0.1.00 build:7640
    [ 5550.371811] build time:201308221655____
    [ 5550.371825] ilm length = 68780(bytes)
    [ 5550.371825] dlm length = 11476(bytes)
    [ 5550.451175] #
    [ 5550.457901] loading fw......
    [ 5550.796383] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740b38d18!
    [ 5550.796384] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740b27b80!
    [ 5550.796384] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740b27bf8!
    [ 5550.796385] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740b38e88!
    [ 5550.796386] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740b38c38!
    [ 5550.796387] RTMP_TimerListAdd: add timer obj ffffc64740b38e18!
    [ 5550.796444] cfg_mode=5
    [ 5550.796446] wmode_band_equal(): Band Not Equal!
    [ 5550.796559] Key1Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 5550.796570] Key2Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 5550.796581] Key3Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 5550.796592] Key4Str is Invalid key length(0) or Type(0)
    [ 5550.796832] 1. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 5550.796833] 2. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 5550.796834] NVM is Efuse and its size =1d[1e0-1fc] 
    [ 5550.807751] /root/src/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916/os/linux/../../chips/mt76x0.c:2114 assert (pAd->TxPower[choffset].Channel == 36)failed
    [ 5550.818252] ERROR!!! E2PROM: WRONG VERSION 0x2, should be 1
    [ 5550.822377] mt76x0_read_tx_alc_info_from_eeprom: EEPROM_MT76x0_TEMPERATURE_OFFSET (0xD1) = 0xf8
    [ 5550.822378] mt76x0_read_tx_alc_info_from_eeprom: TemperatureOffset = 0xfffffff8
    [ 5550.822378] Temperature Tx ALC not enabled
    [ 5550.839378] 3. Phy Mode = 31
    [ 5550.839379] AntCfgInit: primary/secondary ant 0/1
    [ 5550.844637] RTMPSetPhyMode: channel is out of range, use first channel=1 
    [ 5550.846035] MCS Set = ff 00 00 00 01
    [ 5550.855972] <==== rt28xx_init, Status=0
    [ 5550.857128] 0x1300 = 00064300
    [ 5550.857129] RTMPDrvSTAOpen(1):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 5550.857255] RTMPDrvSTAOpen(2):Check if PDMA is idle!
    [ 5551.014244] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00007fff13453d00
    [ 5551.014316] IP: [<ffffffffc0df441a>] rt_ioctl_siwpmksa+0x8a/0x140 [mt7650u_sta]
    [ 5551.014402] PGD 116cca067 PUD 11599c067 PMD 117fd0067 PTE 800000010a6d3867
    [ 5551.014467] Oops: 0001 [#1] SMP
    [ 5551.014494] Modules linked in: fuse nfnetlink_queue nfnetlink_log nfnetlink binfmt_misc wl(PO) mt7650u_sta(O) snd_hda_codec_hdmi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp btusb btrtl btbcm btintel uvcvideo bluetooth videobuf2_vmalloc kvm_intel dcdbas videobuf2_memops iTCO_wdt snd_hda_codec_realtek videobuf2_v4l2 iTCO_vendor_support kvm hid_rmi dell_smm_hwmon videobuf2_core videodev irqbypass snd_hda_codec_generic cfg80211 snd_hda_intel rtsx_usb_ms hid_multitouch memstick pcspkr media snd_soc_rt5640 snd_hda_codec snd_soc_ssm4567 snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_core snd_hda_core joydev evdev snd_hwdep snd_compress snd_pcm sg serio_raw i915 wmi snd_timer snd shpchp dw_dmac battery video elan_i2c dell_rbtn rfkill i2c_i801 dw_dmac_core snd_soc_sst_acpi mei_me mei snd_soc_sst_match lpc_ich drm_kms_helper
    [ 5551.015186]  soundcore i2c_smbus acpi_pad ac button drm i2c_algo_bit tpm_tis tpm_tis_core tpm i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb mfd_core ext4 crc16 usbhid jbd2 crc32c_generic fscrypto ecb mbcache sr_mod cdrom sd_mod crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd ahci libahci psmouse xhci_pci xhci_hcd libata ehci_pci ehci_hcd scsi_mod r8169 mii usbcore usb_common fan thermal sdhci_acpi sdhci mmc_core fjes i2c_hid hid
    [ 5551.015700] CPU: 0 PID: 838 Comm: wpa_supplicant Tainted: P           O    4.8.0-kali1-amd64 #1 Debian 4.8.5-1kali1
    [ 5551.015775] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 3543/0MGXC6, BIOS A00 10/25/2014
    [ 5551.015832] task: ffff906d98270080 task.stack: ffff906d934a4000
    [ 5551.015874] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc0df441a>]  [<ffffffffc0df441a>] rt_ioctl_siwpmksa+0x8a/0x140 [mt7650u_sta]
    [ 5551.015974] RSP: 0018:ffff906d934a7ca8  EFLAGS: 00010297
    [ 5551.016016] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 00007fff13453d00 RCX: 0000000000000000
    [ 5551.016067] RDX: 0000000000005013 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffc64740b25000
    [ 5551.016119] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
    [ 5551.016169] R10: 0000000000000036 R11: ffffffffc0df4390 R12: ffffc64740b25000
    [ 5551.016224] R13: ffff906d0ca3d000 R14: ffffffff8429a888 R15: ffffffffc0df4390
    [ 5551.016275] FS:  00007f275db5a880(0000) GS:ffff906d9ec00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
    [ 5551.016338] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
    [ 5551.016382] CR2: 00007fff13453d00 CR3: 0000000116c12000 CR4: 00000000003406f0
    [ 5551.016437] Stack:
    [ 5551.016456]  ffff906cacae6a00 ffff906d941d1000 ffff906d93dbd900 0000000000000024
    [ 5551.016522]  000000005485238f ffff906d2a0b0540 ffff906d934a7e20 0000000000000000
    [ 5551.016586]  0000000000008b36 ffffffff841ce8b8 ffff906d0ca3d000 00007fff13453d00
    [ 5551.016652] Call Trace:
    [ 5551.016681]  [<ffffffff841ce8b8>] ? ioctl_standard_iw_point+0x2e8/0x3c0
    [ 5551.016734]  [<ffffffff841cea3a>] ? ioctl_standard_call+0xaa/0xd0
    [ 5551.016783]  [<ffffffff841cec55>] ? wext_handle_ioctl+0x75/0xd0
    [ 5551.016828]  [<ffffffff840fa62f>] ? dev_ioctl+0x29f/0x580
    [ 5551.016871]  [<ffffffff840bf8bd>] ? sock_ioctl+0x11d/0x280
    [ 5551.016916]  [<ffffffff83e1334f>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x9f/0x5f0
    [ 5551.016962]  [<ffffffff83dff6d0>] ? vfs_read+0x90/0x130
    [ 5551.017006]  [<ffffffff83e13914>] ? SyS_ioctl+0x74/0x80
    [ 5551.017047]  [<ffffffff841e18f6>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0xc/0x96
    [ 5551.017100] Code: 00 bd 9c ff ff ff eb 78 48 85 db 0f 84 a0 00 00 00 48 83 3d 40 23 04 00 02 89 c5 76 0e 48 83 3d 5c a5 06 00 00 0f 84 a5 00 00 00 <8b> 03 83 f8 03 74 6b 83 f8 02 74 70 83 f8 01 0f 94 c0 0f b6 c0 
    [ 5551.017394] RIP  [<ffffffffc0df441a>] rt_ioctl_siwpmksa+0x8a/0x140 [mt7650u_sta]
    [ 5551.017477]  RSP <ffff906d934a7ca8>
    [ 5551.017504] CR2: 00007fff13453d00
    [ 5551.027427] ---[ end trace 59de0c89298499a0 ]---
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do this on my old laptop, (hp g6 with RT5390).

many of the fields stay blank, including ssid i had once upon a time populated this, but it wasn't needed.

the main thing to do was there were a couple of files that needed editing pre-build.

I booted up my old laptop to check... re-extracted the tar and did a meld...

config.mk

```
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n
changed to:
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
```

pci_main_dev.c

commented out some logic that was preventing:

```
SET_NETDEV_DEV(net_dev,&(pci-dev->dev))
```

(without that network manager won't be supported, but the logic was for kernel 2.6.0, can't remember if i really had that old of a kernel on that matchine... probably did at some point).

rt_linux.c

I edited the skb->tail to cast it as an unasigned int 32 bit.

and finally in the makefile:

- I removed the logic around and changed the value of;
  CHIPSET = 5390
- deleted all platforms par PC
- deleted all logic around MAKE
  MAKE = make

(you probably won't have to go through all these steps as i imagine by now they have a better release but there they are...)

regarding the dat file, I had changed 3x value; (but they should not be needed if you compile for network manager, as i did later on).

```
- SSID=
- EncrypType=wpa-psk
- WPAPSK=
```

once all build I placed the dat files in;

```
/etc/Wireless/RT5390STA/RT5390STA.dat
/etc/Wireless/RT5390STA/RT5390STACard.dat
```

If you want or it helps, to compare I can copy the .dat file.

UPDATE: finding modules to blacklist; use;

```
sudo lscpi -v | less
```

example output from my current machine;

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
        DeviceName: SP1
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3165
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
        Memory at f1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number dc-53-60-ff-ff-5f-cb-f2
        Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

in this case i would blacklist in /etc/modprobe.d/wifi.conf

```
blacklist iwlwifi
```

repeat until on the wireless device you see:

```
Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

UPDATE:

I dug out my tp-link usb adapter (OP is trying to sort usb rather than pci device).

I've not compiled the source for the usb, this just worked with my kernel and firmware blobs already available.

```
[   25.502040] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   25.660113] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=5572
[   25.660124] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   25.660129] usb 2-1: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[   25.660133] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Ralink
[   25.660136] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 1.0
[   25.827234] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   25.977689] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5592, rev 0222 detected
[   26.088458] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 000f detected
[   26.090545] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[   26.092720] usbcore: registered new interface driver rt2800usb
[   26.122102] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[   26.122379] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
```

here are the current kernel modules:

```
$ lsmod  | grep rt2
rt2800usb              28672  0
rt2x00usb              20480  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              81920  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              45056  3 rt2800lib,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
mac80211              569344  4 rt2800lib,iwlmvm,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb
cfg80211              471040  4 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,rt2x00lib,mac80211
usbcore               208896  6 rt2800usb,rt2x00usb,ehci_hcd,xhci_pci,xhci_hcd,ehci_pci
```

The firmware blob is from this package:

```
firmware-misc-nonfree: /lib/firmware/rt2870.bin
```

If OP wants, I can test the source package with this usb device?

Comment: most of the steps that you mentioned are already done on this new release. But I can't seem to get it to work with network manager or without it. After I compiled the the source code the and I move the RT.. & RT..Card files to their proper directory should I need to reboot or kill network manager or should the wifi symbol show up automatically after? because with a site_survey I can capture some traffic around me which means it's working just not with network manager.

Comment: `sudo modprobe rt2800pci`

Comment: nothing still the same.

Comment: confirm you have the module loaded using `lsmod | grep rt2` also the module name may have changed perhaps `modprobe rt2870pci`, once you've done all this use `sudo lspci -vvv | less` and look for wireless `/Wire`, what kernel module is loaded? perhaps you have to blacklist another module getting in the way.

Comment: module is loaded lsmod | grep rt2
`rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib              94208  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00lib              53248  5 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2x00mmio,rt2800pci
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
mac80211              651264  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
cfg80211              573440  3 wl,rt2x00lib,mac80211
`  with lspci I can only get broadcom and Eth

Comment: `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/wifi.conf` then add a `blacklist ...` for whatever broadcom or whatever other wifi modules are loaded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49343/discussion-between-francesc-and-mikejonesey).

Answer (score 0):

Look into this package: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mt7610u_wifi_sta/
I'm sure you will find precious information